# How to keep the excel "list changes on new sheet" track change sheet permanently?

Tags: vba, excel, revision-history

The history sheet only appears when the file is saved (I am fine with this) but then disappears as soon as you reopen the file! How can I keep a running log of who changes what and when? I would like to have the history tab that is autofilled via track changes permanently adhered to the worksheet and it automatically updates every time the files gets resaved.

Comment: If you have an SQL Server or a SharePoint site available then I'd much rather recommend that you use any of those tools for a lasting and reliable revision history.

Comment: @Ralph no sharepoint or sql im afaif